# Apache Webserver High Disk Usage Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, hard-drive, apache-http-server, webserver

I'm using Apache packaged through WAMP to host a forum for my small gaming community and also to host some installers for free to play games.

When downloading files larger than 2 GB from the webserver, the httpd.exe process will occasionally fully utilize the drive that the files are stored on and the download will freeze from the client's perspective.

The actual read rate of the httpd.exe process is extremely low as well when this happens.

Apache is running on a [2TB HGST Enterprise Drive](http://www.hgst.com/hard-drives/enterprise-hard-drives/enterprise-sata-drives/ultrastar-7k4000) setup as JBOD.

Resource Monitor in Windows shows 100% Highest Active Time for the disk and read speeds of ~4 MB/sec.

Does anyone know what's causing this or how I can further figure out what Apache is doing?

Comment: Well chalk it up to an amateur mistake.  The drive appears to be 68% fragmented.  I'm fairly sure this would be causing the issues.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect its hard drive fragmentation causing your issues.

Run a chkdsk on the drive before you defrag it, sometimes there is file system corruption when drives get high fragmentation, you need to sort that out Before you defrag the drive.